# If $f$ is entire and $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}f(z)=0$ then $f\equiv 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to understand the proof of the following fact: If $f$ is entire and $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}f(z)=0$ then $f\equiv 0$.

The proof uses the maximum modulus principle, which states: If $f$ is analytic in a connected region $A$ and continuous on the boundary of $A$ then either $f$ is constant or $|f|$ attains its maximum only on the boundary of $A$.

*Proof.* Fix $z_0$. For $R>|z_0|$ let $M_R$ be the maximum of $|f(z)|$ on the circle $|z|=R$. The maximum modulus theorem says that $|f(z_0)|<M_R$. Since $f(z)$ goes to 0 as $R$ goes to $\infty$, it must be that $M_R$ also goes to 0. So $|f(z_0)|=0$. This holds for any $z_0$, so $f(z)\equiv 0$.

What I'm confused about: So in order to use the maximum modulus principle to get $|f(z_0)|<M_R$, we must first need that $f$ is not constant on the disk $|z|<R$. But how do we know that?

Or could it be that there is a typo? For example, should it be that $|f(z_0)|\leq M_R$?

Are we just starting out by assuming that $f$ is not constant on the disk, and then getting a contradiction at the end saying that $f$ is in fact constant?

Comment: If $f$ is entire and $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)=0$ then $f$ is bounded, hence it should be constant due to [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)). A constant function which tends to zero is zero itself.

Comment: @dsw How do you conclude from $f$ entire and $\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty}f(z)=0$ that $f$ is bounded?

Comment: An entire function is bounded on any compact set; because our $f$ tends to zero at infinity, it is bounded outside some compact set (that is, in some neighbourhood of infinity). Therefore, $f$ is bounded on the whole $\mathbb{C}$, as claimed.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is a constant on $B(z_0,R)$ then $|f(z_0)| \leq M_R$ by continuity since it is constant on the closed disk also. It does not require any theorem from Complex Analysis!